# Show that $R[x^2]$, the ring of polynomials in $x^2$, is a subring of $R[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am quite confused about this problem. My first question is what does $R[x^2]$ look like? Is it like $f(x)=a_nx^{2n}+...+a_1x^2+a_0$ or does it look different?

I was going to try proving this by showing $R[x^2]$ is closed under subtraction and multiplication, but it seems impossible to show multiplication.

I understand that it is a subring in the same way that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$, but I have no idea how to show it.

Any help is welcome, thank you!

Comment: What you mentioned as your guess for $f$ is right. And to show that it is closed under multiplication, can you prove that for two polynomials $f$ and $g$ each with even degree terms, then their product must have even degree terms?

Comment: $R[x^2]$ is the smallest ring containing $R$ and $x^2$. By definition $R[x]$ contains $R$, it contains $x^2$ as $x\in R[x]$ and since $R[x]$ is a ring, $x^2\in R[x]$. Therefore $R[x^2]\subseteq R[x]$.